# High-performance knapsack variant

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, knapsack-problem

I often (well, a few times a year) come across problems which are particular cases of a knapsack problem, like so:

> Given a set S of integers and a number n of sacks, find the smallest integer N such that S can be partitioned into n sets S1, S2, ..., Sn such that the product of each is at most N.

(Variants giving lower bounds, upper bounds, and estimates are also interesting, but exact values are the primary interest.)

So far each time this comes up I end up writing my own code, customized to the particular situation. But there is a lot known about the knapsack problem and similar (bin packing, etc.) and I'm sure there is existing code which could handle this type of problem better than what I'm doing. Alternately, there should at least be good algorithms for doing this efficiently which should scale better than what I cook up on the spur of the moment. Ideas?

Comment: the tag language-agnostic and asking for libraries doesn't mix altogether that well. And you should specify whether you're interested in approximations or a precise solution.

Comment: @Paul I'm happy to move to any language that has a good solution. As in my third paragraph, I'm primarily interested in exact solutions but approximations and bounds are of some interest as well.